# Bot token not being read in from environment variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, dotenv

Learning to write a Discord bot. I have a .env file set up for my bot secret key, but am getting `discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.`

If I put the secret key directly into the `client.run(KEY_HERE)` it connects just fine, no errors. It's only having an issue when I'm calling it from the .env file.

File tree is just the project root, with bot.py and .env contained in it. I'm using PyCharm.

bot.py:

```
import os

import discord
import dotenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("connected")

client.run(token)
```

.env:

```
DISCORD_TOKEN={"secret_key_here"}
```

Here is the full error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 258, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 222, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 UNAUTHORIZED (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 16, in <module>
    client.run(token)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 598, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 579, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 542, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 400, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 262, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Figured it out. The issue was that the key in .env didn't need to be in braces or quotes.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer.